# sys.application.add_load event is not firing in chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am working in c# asp.net 3.5 application.I have many ajax control in my page.
The function in sys.application.add_load event in the updatepanel is not firing in chrome. But in IE and Mozilla it is working properly.

Thanks in advance.